# Joda-Time, How to pick up format for string parsing?

Tags: java, parsing, date, time, jodatime

Following code using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library

```
Long timestamp = DateTime.parse(dateInString,DateTimeFormat.shortTime()).getMillis();
```

generates:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "12.05.2014 11:42:35.808" is malformed at ".05.2014 11:42:35.808"
```

I tryed all `DateTimeFormat.*` but each format produces error.

How to fix it?

Comment: 12.05.2014 is in dd.MM.yyyy format or MM.dd.yyyy format

Comment: I tryed different variants. Can you provide working code for "12.05.2014 11:42:35.808" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) matching your pattern, and use that. Your pattern certainly isn't a "short time" pattern, given that you've got a date in there as well...

For example:

```
// Possibly MM.dd.yyyy - we don't know what 12.05.2014 is meant to represent
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                                            .withLocale(Locale.US)
                                            .withZoneUTC(); // Adjust accordingly
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parse(text);
long millis = dateTime.getMillis();
```

Comment: awesome. I am very confusing about *HH* and *hh* *MM* and *mm* and so on. Where can I read about it?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: On the `DateTimeFormat` javadoc? http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");
   Long timestamp = DateTime.parse(dateInString,pattern).getMillis();
```

Comment: How is anyone going to represent a time in the afternoon with that pattern?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

Date DateNow= new Date( );  
SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss");
String timestamp= sdf.format(DateNow);
```

Comment: The [correct answer by Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24452273/642706) is thread-safe.